# Delayed waves existing MIMO eigenmode transmission

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, mimo, channel, svd

Assume that the numbers of transmitting antennas, receiving antennas, and delayed waves are $N_t$, $N_r$, and $N_p$, respectively. The channel matrix is three-dimensional ($N_r$, $N_t$, $N_p$).

In eigenmode transmission, when $N_p=1$, the channel matrix is subjected to singular value decomposition.

How to perform eigenmode transmission when $N_p>1$?

Comment: Haven't heard the term "delayed waves" in this context! Is it the same as "multipath components"? Or something else?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's as you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $N_p$ is, as discussed in the comments, the number of taps in a multipath channel.

While [higher-order singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition) on tensors with more than two dimensions *are* a thing, the fact that the eigenvectors turn out to be tensors themselves makes it not as desirable as method of MIMO precoding.

Instead, the problem is solved in two steps: The "multipath" dimension describes the channel impulse response between a transmit and a receive antenna. You thus start by looking for *common* eigenvectors of all the convolution matrices that arises when you convolve with these channel impulse responses.

Luckily, convolution is an LTI system, so *all* these channels have the *same* set of eigenvectors, namely, harmonic oscillations.

So, you first decompose the signals you might want to send into harmonic oscillations: Exactly what the (discrete, since we're discrete in time here) Fourier transform does! So, you use the IDFT as a means to transform each possible transmit signal onto an ONB of eigenvectors of (sampled) harmonic oscillations.

Ok, so we know that when we apply the "$N_p$-direction" aspect of out channel tensor to our thus decomposed signal, we get the input out, changed by nothing but a multiplication with a scalar (the individual Fourier coefficient  of the channel impulse response). The IDFT transforms each of our $N_r\times N_t$ multipath channels (each of $N_p$ components) into a set of completely independent scalar channels! Thus, you reduce the problem of an $N_r\times N_t \times N_p$ channel into a problem of $N_p$ independent $N_r\times N_t (\times 1)$ channels. Much, much easier, and lossless! We already have a solution for these channels, so we're done.

Technically, this decomposition is most commonly done via OFDM – in fact, I've never seen a practically employed wideband (i.e., $N_p > 1$) MIMO system that wasn't based on relatively classical OFDM. So, you divide your transmit signal(s) into individual frequency components using OFDM narrowband enough that each of them only sees a single-tap (i.e., frequency-flat) channel, then for these narrow band components, each "sees" a different $N_r\times N_t$ matrix, and you do "normal" MIMO on each of them.

OFDM is probably a technology you would want to read into if you're working with MIMO.