# How to do MIMO precoding for OFDM?

Tags: ofdm, mimo

I studied OFDM, MIMO, and MU-MIMO, but I'm not sure how it works when MIMO and OFDM are combined.
I can't find good literature that talks about MIMO-OFDM.
I want to understand how to use eigenmode method for MIMO-OFDM.

Comment: You do OFDM first, then you do MIMO on each subcarrier separately, as I described in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delayed waves existing MIMO eigenmode transmission](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89583/delayed-waves-existing-mimo-eigenmode-transmission)

Comment: Thanks!!  For channel matrix estimation, OFDM pilot is used ? Then UE feedback channel matrix to Base Station?

Comment: Pilots are the most common way, yes. How the estimate gets back to the sender depends – systems are different. In a TDD system, you can (given sufficient switching speed) assume channels to be reciprocal, so that on expectation, channel estimates are the same between an TX and an RX antenna, and the same can be achieved through both estimating their receive channel; but usually, yes, you quantize the channel estimate and send it back some way. In which way, how often, and using what method, that happens is subject to the individual system you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks. IIs the same pilot signal used for OFDM equalization and feedback channel matrix calculation? And is that DM-RS?

Comment: I don't know which system you're referring to. Systems are different, as said. Don't confuse the underlying techniques like OFDM or MU-MIMO with specific implementations, like Wimax or IEEE802.11ax.

Comment: Can you tell me about the general MU-MIMO-OFDM case for 5g?

Comment: uff, no, that standard is a bit bigger than I have read :) MU-MIMO is in 3gpp release 13, and that would put it in LTE / 4G, not in 5G, so, not quite you mean that or a different technology. But yeah, since that is a cellular technology with base stations, what other channel estimate would you use? (I still don't know what DM-RS means, but the standards are publicly available, so you can just read them. "DM" in the 3GPP context usually refers to the PDSCH, so yes? Probably?)

Comment: DM-RS(Demodulation reference signal)of PDSCH.I want to implement mu-mimo-ofdm on MATLAB.I already implemented SISO-OFDM using LS channel estimate & linear interpolation .